# npm WARN package.json CrackingJS@0.0.1 No repository field

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

- I am trying to support the how to crack a interview repository
- I am trying to crack the interviews for JS position
- They are using mocha and chai, so I am trying to commit the code in
  JS
- I am trying to execute the below steps but I am failing at the below
  step, npm install

  git clone https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci.git
      cd ctci/javascript
      npm install
      npm install -g mocha
      mocha --recursive
- I am getting the below error
- I have installed Node.js after that tried npm install in ctci folder of javascript
- providing you the link for screensshot to show where node is
  installed and where I kept ctci
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RMGlUYWZUa2lZY3c/view?usp=sharing

  anis-MacBook-Pro:javascript Raj$ npm install
  npm WARN package.json CrackingJS@0.0.1 No repository field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a warning, not an error. It is simply pointing out that the `package.json` does not contain a [`"repository"`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) field, which is a recommended field to have for convenience. You can safely ignore most warnings, especially ones like this one.